# Как сделать чтобы нарисованный через border контур облачка диалога обтекал повсюду?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, html5, css3

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}

#box {
  margin: 50px;
  background: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px gray;
}

#pointer{
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  top: 10px;
  left: 75px;
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: white;
  }
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
<div id="pointer"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`box-shadow` может рисоваться только на границе "бокса", это свойство никак не заставить считать непрозрачную часть границы краем элемента. Однако можно воспользоваться трансформацией поворота. Так как тень рисуется подо всем квадратом, то приходится использовать два псевдоэлемента: один снизу для тени, другой сверху для скрытия границы.

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}

#box {
  margin: 50px;
  background: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px gray;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#box::before, #box::after {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: white;
  top: -15px;
  left: 25px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#box::before {
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px gray;
}

#box::after {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Как вариант, если вам хватает однопиксельной границы, можно аналогично наложить два элемента "хвостика" диалога со смещением вверх на 1 пиксель, чтобы создался эффект границы.